# Why drivers shows error when running in command line?

Tags: python, command-line

My blender file contains drivers and when I run Blender using the command line it gives this error

```
find_node_operation: Failed for (PARAMETERS_EXIT, '')
--------------------------------------------------------------------
Failed to add relation "ID Property -> Done"
Could not find op_to: OperationKey(type: PARAMETERS, component name: '', operation code: PARAMETERS_EXIT)
```

How to fix this?

Comment: Which operating system are you using? Are you running it from a Linux Terminal or the CMD from Windows? Also please share your blend file https://blend-exchange.com

Comment: Windows 11 CMD/Terminal

Comment: can you share the blend file and the exact command you are executing

Comment: @HarryMcKenzie, I got the solution. the issue was there was a custom property in the `Collection` custom properties panel and that custom property was used as a driver in material inputs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution.

The issue was there was a custom property in the `Collection` custom properties panel and that custom property was used as a driver in material inputs that's why I was getting this error.

```
find_node_operation: Failed for (PARAMETERS_EXIT, '')
--------------------------------------------------------------------
Failed to add relation "ID Property -> Done"
Could not find op_to: OperationKey(type: PARAMETERS, component name: '', operation code: PARAMETERS_EXIT)
```